# Can't find the hash key when using Remote Desktop Connection (Connecting from OSX to Windows 7 on MacBook Pro)?

Tags: windows-7, macos, remote-desktop

As the title says, I'm using a MacBook Pro to log in to my Windows 7 desktop (using "Remote Desktop Connection").

I've tried all the usual keyboard combinations to get a hash key from within Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (both left and right alt keys on the keyboard) but no characters appear.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key combination to use is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

Sourced from the second comment of [this](http://www.john.geek.nz/2009/01/mac-os-x-remote-desktop-client-uk-keyboard-bug-fix/) blog post.

Comment: Phew, thanks! I'd given up looking but this works perfectly :)

Comment: @fitzrover You are a shining light in the darkness. Thank you.